# Bash script: specify bc output number format

Tags: bash, format

Greetings!

I uses **bс** to make some calculations in my script. For example:

```
bc
scale=6
1/2
.500000
```

For further usage in my script I need "0.500000" insted of ".500000".

Could you help me please to configure bc output number format for my case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get bc(1) to print the leading zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402181/how-do-i-get-bc1-to-print-the-leading-zero)

Answer (score 20):

In one line:

```
printf "%0.6f\n" $(bc -q <<< scale=6\;1/2)
```

Answer (score 5):

Just do all your calculations and output in awk:

```
float_scale=6
result=$(awk -v scale=$floatscale 'BEGIN { printf "%.*f\n", scale, 1/2 }')
```

As an alternative, if you'd prefer to use `bc` and not use AWK alone or with 'bc', Bash's `printf` supports floating point numbers even though the rest of Bash doesn't.

```
result=$(echo "scale=$float_scale; $*" | bc -q 2>/dev/null)
result=$(printf '%*.*f' 0 "$float_scale" "$result")
```

The second line above could instead be:

```
printf -v $result '%*.*f' 0 "$float_scale" "$result"
```

Which works kind of like `sprintf` would and doesn't create a subshell.

Answer (score 4):

Quick and dirty, since `scale` only applies to the decimal digits and `bc` does not seem to have a `sprintf`-like function:

```
$ bc
scale = 6
result = 1 / 2
if (0 <= result && result < 1) {
    print "0"
}
print result;
```

Comment: +1 for this solution: no need to use other tools such as awk.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "scale=3;12/7" | bc -q | sed 's/^\\./0./;s/0*$//;s/\\.$//'
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe here is modified version of the function:

```
float_scale=6

function float_eval()
{
    local stat=0
    local result=0.0
    if [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; then
        result=$(echo "scale=$float_scale; $*" | bc -q | awk '{printf "%f\n", $0}' 2>/dev/null)
        stat=$?
        if [[ $stat -eq 0  &&  -z "$result" ]]; then stat=1; fi
    fi
    echo $result
    return $stat
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you put the bc usage into a little better context?  What are you using the results of bc for?

Given the following in a file called `some_math.bc`

```
scale=6
output=1/2
print output
```

on the command line I can do the following to add a zero:

```
$ bc -q some_math.bc | awk '{printf "%08f\n", $0}'
0.500000
```

If I only needed the output string to have a zero for formatting purposes, I'd use awk.