# Convert tallies to relative probabilities

Tags: bash, math, csv, text-processing

### Background

Create a probability lexicon based on a CSV file of words and tallies. This is a prelude to a text segmentation problem, not a homework problem.

### Problem

Given a CSV file with the following words and tallies:

```
aardvark,10
aardwolf,9
armadillo,9
platypus,5
zebra,1
```

Create a file with probabilities relative to the largest tally in the file:

```
aardvark,1
aardwolf,0.9
armadillo,0.9
platypus,0.5
zebra,0.1
```

Where, for example, `aardvark,1` is calculated as `aardvark,10/10` and `platypus,0.5` is calculated as `platypus,5/10`.

### Question

What is the most efficient way to implement a shell script to create the file of relative probabilities?

### Constraints

- Neither the words nor the numbers are in any order.
- No major programming language (such as Perl, Ruby, Python, Java, C, Fortran, or Cobol).
- Standard Unix tools such as `awk`, `sed`, or `sort` are welcome.
- All probabilities must be relative to the highest probability in the file.
- The words are unique, the numbers are not.
- The tallies are natural numbers.

Thank you!

Comment: @Marshall: `bc` is not "bashcalc" it's "bench calculator" as `dc` is "desk calculator".

Comment: @Dennis: Thank you, apologies for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to read the file twice:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS = FS = ","} {a[$1] = $2} $2 > max {max=$2} END {for (w in a) print w, a[w]/max}' inputfile
```

If you need the output sorted by word:

```
awk ... | sort
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS = FS = ","} {a[$1] = $2; ind[j++] = $1} $2 > max {max=$2} END {n = asort(ind); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print ind[i], a[ind[i]]/max}' inputfile
```

If you need the output sorted by probability:

```
awk ... | sort -t, -k2,2n -k1,1
```

Comment: Not reading the file twice is definitely an efficient approach.

Comment: If you want to format the numbers, you can replace {print w, a[w]/max} with {printf "%s,%.3f\n", w, a[w]/max} (to keep 3 trailing digits)

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'BEGIN{max=0;OFS=FS=","}  $NF>max{max=$NF}NR>FNR {print $1,($2/max) }' file file
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not error-proof but something like this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT=data.cvs
OUTPUT=tally.cvs
DIGITS=1

OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,

maxval=0  # Assuming all $val are positive

while read name val
do
    if (( val > maxval )); then maxval=$val; fi
done < $INPUT

# Make sure $OUTPUT doesn't exist

touch $OUTPUT

while read name val
do
    tally=`echo "scale=$DIGITS; result=$val/$maxval; if (0 <= result && result < 1) { print "0" }; print result" | bc`
    echo "$name,$tally" >> $OUTPUT
done < $INPUT

IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Borrowed from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965411/bash-script-specify-bc-output-number-format), and various googling.

Comment: An excellent answer and a good example of reading CSV files in `bash`. A pure `awk` solution, though, is likely more efficient. Thank you.

Comment: @Dave: Definite props to kurumi