# bad format decimal in bash script

Tags: bash, format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get bc(1) to print the leading zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402181/how-do-i-get-bc1-to-print-the-leading-zero)

I have this problem:

```
x=$(echo "0.81+0.02" |bc)
echo $x
```

Result **.83**

I want see 0.83, but I don't make it.

Answer (score 2):

`echo` doesn't know anything about floating point numbers, it just knows about strings and integers.

You can use `printf` to deal with other data types and specify precise formatting options:

```
printf '%.2f\n' $x
```

Example:

```
imac:barmar $ x=$(echo "0.81+0.02" |bc)
imac:barmar $ printf '%.2f\n' $x
0.83
```

Comment: Is not than simple :-( x=$(echo "0.81+0.02" |bc)
printf "$x.2f\n" $x, result 0.00

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: It should be `'%.2f\n'`, not `'$x.2f\n'`

Comment: Please read the documentation for `printf`, it explains the format string.

Comment: You can't put the printf on the same line as the assignment, they have to be separate statements. See example in my answer.

Comment: I would not use a printf with %.2f because it would print useless zeroes should the value be integer, and would round the numbers should they have more than two significant decimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to append the result to a string already containing the "0" character.

```
x=0
x+=$(echo "0.81+0.02" |bc)
echo $x
```

If you want to be able to handle the case in which the number could be greater than 1 you can use parameter substitution instead

```
x=$(echo "1.81+0.02" | bc )
x=${x/^./0.}
echo $x
```

unfortunately the previous code won't work. The second line is meant to replace the first character, if it is a dot, with the string `0.`, but obviously I made a syntax error. I'm not very knowledgeable of regexps, but this should be exactly what you are looking for.

The following is more cumbersome, but defenetively works.

```
x=$(echo "1.81+0.02" | bc )
if [[ $x == .* ]]; then
   x=0$x
fi
```

Comment: $ x=0
$ x=$(echo "$x+0.81+0.02" |bc)
$ echo $x -> result 0.83 ok. But. $ x=0
$ x+=$(echo "1.81+0.02" |bc)
$ echo $x ->result 01.83 ->bad format.
01.83

Comment: See my other edit, this time works.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in one line:

```
printf '%.2f\n' $(echo 0.82+0.01 | bc)
```

or

```
echo 0.82+0.01 | printf '%.2f\n' $(bc)
```