# Add floating numbers in bash

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying something very easy but all code that I'm trying doesnt work.
I need add two float numbers in bash. I'm doing this:

```
result1=`$CURL -o /dev/null -s -w %{time_total} $url1`
result2=`$CURL -o /dev/null -s -w %{time_total} $url2`
result3=`$CURL -o /dev/null -s -w %{time_total} $url3`
total= `expr $result2 + $result3`

echo $total | $GAWK -F: '{ print "connection_1.value " $1 }'
```

but in the prompt I'm getting this output:

```
./http_response_2: line 12: 0,018+0,255: command not found
connection_1.value
```

I'm trying too do this:

```
result1=`$CURL -o /dev/null -s -w %{time_total} $url1`
result2=`$CURL -o /dev/null -s -w %{time_total} $url2`
result3=`$CURL -o /dev/null -s -w %{time_total} $url3`
total= `$result2 + $result3 | bc`
```

getting the same result.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove the space in between `total=` and ``expr...`

Comment: replace your last line in the last snippet by: `total=$(bc <<< "$result2+$result3")`

Comment: @fedorqui thanks, but I'm getting this: expr: no integer argument

Comment: Plus, there is comma, not a decimal point in `0,018+0,255`. If it is not a typo, then it should be `total=$(tr ',' '.' <<< "$result2 + $result3" | bc -l)`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf with you suggestion I'm getting this error: `(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error`

Comment: ^^ Try answer in my comment...

Comment: @anishsane thanks! but the zero is missing, I'm getting this: `connection_2.value .374`

Comment: ^^ This can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402181/how-do-i-get-bc1-to-print-the-leading-zero

Comment: That's because you have commas in your numbers. To replace commas with periods: `total=$(bc <<< "${result2//,/.}+${result3//,/.}")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 issues:

1. There should be no space between `total=` & `
2. echo missing before `$result2 + $result3`
3. There is comma in your input, instead of decimal point.

Fixing all these issues:

```
total=$(tr ',' '.' <<< "$result2 + $result3" | bc -l)
```

If you are concerned about the leading 0 before decimal point, try:

```
total=$(tr ',' '.' <<< "$result2 + $result3" | bc -l | xargs printf "%g")
```

Comment: thank you very much master :) `total=$(tr ',' '.' <<< "$result2 + $result3" | bc -l | xargs printf "%g")` solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing commas with dots, don't produce commas in the first place.

They emerge from localization, so use LC_ALL=C as prefix, like:

```
LC_ALL=C curl -o /dev/null -s -w %{time_total} www.google.com
```

and abandon the outdated backticks, use $(...) instead:

```
result1=$(LC_ALL=C $CURL -o /dev/null -s -w %{time_total} $url1)
```