# Adding a leading zero to a float number in a bash script

Tags: regex, bash, variables, math, logic

My script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "number 1 :";
read number1
echo -n "number 2 :";
read number2    
jlh=$(echo $number1 + $number2 | bc -l | sed 's/^\./0./');
    echo "your result : $number1 + $number2 = $jlh "
```

if input for number 1 is `-1` , and number 2 is `0.9`, why the result only `-.1`.

I want to show the zero like this.

```
Your result : -1 + 0.9 = -0.1
```

How I can do it?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965411/bash-script-specify-bc-output-number-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you by now just consider the case `.NNN`, but not the `-.NNN`, that is having the minus `-` sign before:

With this it should work:

```
sed    -e 's/^\./0./'       -e 's/^-\./-0./'
           start with .         start with -.
```

All together;

```
jlh=$(echo $number1 + $number2 | bc -l | sed -e 's/^\./0./' -e 's/^-\./-0./');
```

Comment: oh, thank you, that work in my bash script. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Great! Consider accepting the answer if the problem is already solved. Cheers