# How do I print the "zero" between the minus and the decimal places on Bash shell

Tags: bash, dc

With dc external tool bash tend to not print at the right of the decimal point.

```
#!/bin/bash    
a[0]=-0.5    
`echo "scale=10;${a[0]}/1"|bc -l`
```

With the command represented above bash will print `-.5000000000`.

How can I add the zero between the minus signal and the point `-0.5000000000`

PS: I do print `a[1]=0` with 10 decimal cases?

Comment: google 'bash bc print leading 0' and you'll get a list of answers (hint: `bc|dc` can't do this), eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402181/how-do-i-get-bc1-to-print-the-leading-zero, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482353/adding-a-leading-zero-to-a-float-number-in-a-bash-script, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292087/how-do-i-get-bc-to-start-decimal-fractions-with-a-leading-zero

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `bc` you may consider this `awk` that does floating point match and formatting using `printf`:

```
a[0]=-0.5

awk -v n="${a[0]}" 'BEGIN{printf "%.10f\n", n/1}'
```

```
-0.5000000000
```

Comment: No, but a similar command worked https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292087/how-do-i-get-bc-to-start-decimal-fractions-with-a-leading-zero Thank you

Comment: ok but same command works here in this demo: https://ideone.com/9ldj5q