# expr: non-integer argument. How to subtract dot-decimal numbers

Tags: bash

I am trying to subtract two numbers by running the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
cur_length=`cat length.txt`
cur_pos=`cat pos.txt`

diff=`$(expr $cur_length - $cur_pos)`
echo "$diff"
```

But the output says expr has some issue:

```
+++ expr 235.68 - 145.9
expr: non-integer argument
+ diff=
+ echo ''
```

I have searched for "expr: non-integer argument" on the net, but nothing involves dot-decimal numbers.
How can I subtract numbers like this?  235.68 - 145.9

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bash doesn't do fractions, just integers.  Use `bc` instead:

```
$ echo  '235.68 - 145.9' | bc
89.78
```

That result can, of course, be put in a shell variable the same way that you were doing with `expr`:

```
$ diff="$(echo  '235.68 - 145.9' | bc)"
$ echo $diff
89.78
```

Comment: Just a follow up question. In my case I have: `for RSQRD in $(seq 0.2 0.2 0.8); do
 echo "===================================================================="
 echo "The r-squared lower LD-threshold is: " $RSQRD
 UPPERRSQRD=$(echo  $RSQRD + 0.2 | bc)
 echo "The r-squared upper LD-threshold is: " $UPPERRSQRD
done`. Which results in for instance `.4` instead of `0.4`. How can have it produce the "0"?

Comment: Ah. I found my own answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18547844/4322048. Now the code is: `for RSQRD in $(seq 0.2 0.2 0.8); do
 echo "===================================================================="
 echo "The r-squared lower LD-threshold is: " $RSQRD
 UPPERRSQRD=$(printf "%0.1f\n" $(bc -q <<< scale=1\;$RSQRD+0.2))
 echo "The r-squared upper LD-threshold is: " $UPPERRSQRD done`. And this works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Difference between two non-integer numbers using a function and `bc`:

```
function diff {
    diff="$(echo $2 - $1 | bc)"
    echo $diff
}

diff 5.0 1.0  #gives output: 4.0
diff 1.0 5.0  #gives output: -4.0
```